# JQuery Validation Not Reliable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a web application I have inherited, and it uses JQuery (jquery.form-validator.min.js) form validation.  Every test I run on it, the form seems to work perfectly, as it was intended.  However, at least once/day, a record is getting into the database with required fields being NULL.  Whenever I try to replicate the record through the form, it won't let me submit because the validation rightfully detects the missing information and then blocks it.  Has anyone had reliability issues with the jquery.form-validator?  Or, does anyone have any suggestions for how to track down how these rogue records are getting into the system?  Should I just rewrite it to use server-side validation?  I'm using .Net MVC

Comment: Rule 1. Never trust user input. Client side validation is a nice bonus but you must always validate on the server. MVC has all this functionality built in. Apply validation attributes to your properties (e.g. `[Required]`, include `@Html.ValidationMesageFor()` in the view for your properties and include the relevant `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts and you get both client side and server side validation. And it all works even if the client disables javascript or a malicious user bypasses your script and posts invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check in your model class and see if you are also using

```
[required]
public string yourvariable {get;set;}
```

for your variables.

And if possible, update your database to reject nulls for the required fields.

Comment: If you do this though, won't it get overridden when you update your model?

Answer (score 0):

you should do both client validation and server validaiton.
user can disable browser's javascript,if that,the client validation all not work